# Issue with repeated moduleServer calls on tab switch

Tags: r, shiny

I am using Shiny to create an application with multiple tabs. Each tab utilizes the same module but might use different parameters. I've noticed that when I switch tabs, the observeEvent inside the module gets erroneously triggered.

When I click on the "Reset Data" button in "Tab 1", then switch to "Tab 2", and come back to "Tab 1", the alert gets triggered without any further interaction on my part.

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to prevent this behavior?

Here's a minimal reproducible example:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyalert)
library(shinyjs)

# UI for the dynamic module
mod_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    actionButton(ns("reinitData"), "Reset Data"),
  )
}

# Server for the dynamic module
mod_server <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    ns <- session$ns

    observeEvent(input$reinitData, {
      shinyalert("Reset", "Data has been reset.", type = "success")
    })
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyalert(),
  useShinyjs(),
  tabsetPanel(
    id = "main_tabs",
    tabPanel("Tab 1", mod_ui("mod1")),
    tabPanel("Tab 2", mod_ui("mod2"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  observeEvent(input$main_tabs, {
    active_tab <- input$main_tabs

    if (active_tab == "Tab 1") {
      mod_server("mod1")
    } else if (active_tab == "Tab 2") {
      mod_server("mod2")
    }

  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what's your purpose of the `observeEvent(input$main_tabs` observer in the main app. You basically re-initialize the module servers when you switch a tab. You don't need to do this, just initialize them once when your app starts:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  mod_server("mod1")
  mod_server("mod2")
}
```